# timed notification after user logs out of app

Tags: android, notifications

I need to set up a periodic notification to remind users to place an order on my app, every monday and Wednesday. The notification should pop up whether or not the app is "on" or not (i.e. whether it has been destroyed, pause or is the main activity in memory).

I don't understand, from the developers documentation and from online tutorials, whether I need to:
- simply set up a notification.
- use alarmanager.
- user broadcastreceiver.
- use a service that uses alarmanager that sends a notification.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to combine all the things AlarmManager + BroadcastReceiver + Notification + Service(Optional).

1. First thing is that you will have to decide, on which day and time you want to notify the user.
2. Create a method which will set the notification using the `AlarmManager + PendingIntent` and set the Broadcast Receiver intent for your Pending Intent.
3. When your broadcast receiver called on time then create a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Use use alarmanager to notify the use and set alarmanager repeated  time 24 hours. Via android time function check the time and give your notification.

Thanks